# whereBetween issue, return wrong records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having a strange issue with the whereBetween Date
If the start date and end date are the same then it doesn't fetch the results.

lets say start date is: 2019-12-20 and end date is 2019-12-20
but i don't get the result unless i make the changes to the end date like: 2019-12-21
even though I don't have anything from the 2019-12-21 but doing that, it fetches the results from the 2019-12-20 which is really weird.

Here is the code:

```
 $start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->format('Y-m-d');
 $end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->format('Y-m-d');

 $user_listings =  UserListing::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
              ->where('is_found_before', 1)
              ->latest('updated_at')
              ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$start_date, $end_date])->paginate(20);
```

and here are the screenshots.
[image]

and query generated
[image]

i don't understand why do i have to select end date as: 2019-12-21 to see the results of 2019-12-20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is treating `2019-12-20` as `2019-12-20 00:00:00`, so it excludes everything on that day. Pass in the full timestamp with beginning of day and end of day instead:

```
// Time will be 00:00:00
$start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->startOfDay()->toDateTimeString(); 
// Time will be 23:59:59
$end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->endOfDay()->toDateTimeString();
```

Comment: You are right, it was expecting as 2019-12-20 00:00:00 and to exclude that 00:00:00 time i used the format('Y-m-d') so it could exclude the 00:00:00 timestamp but it didn't work however your solution worked like a charm.